# How to add a top n column based on another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Example dataframe:

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
Item_Name  Order ID
Basket       a
Carpet       b
Basket       c
Carpet       d
Rug          e
```

I want to have a new column called "Top 2 Items" which indicates whether or not the item name is top 2 based on frequency, for all rows in the dataframe. So ideally, the column should say "top 2" for all the rows except the last one. How do I achieve this in python?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using `value_counts` you can return a sorted list of the frequency, so take the first 2 elements and use those with `np.where` to label your new column.

```
import numpy as np

top2 = df['Item_Name'].value_counts().index[0:2]
df['Top 2 Items'] = np.where(df['Item_Name'].isin(top2), 'top 2', None)

#  Item_Name Order ID Top 2 Items
#0    Basket        a       top 2
#1    Carpet        b       top 2
#2    Basket        c       top 2
#3    Carpet        d       top 2
#4       Rug        e        None
```

---

If you want to deal with *ties* where you might want to keep all items that are at least tied with the 2 most frequent occurrences then you can use `.nlargest` with `keep='all'` instead of slicing the index. Here I added a few rows so that there were 3 items all tied for the largest

```
top2 = df['Item_Name'].value_counts().nlargest(2, keep='all').index
df['Top 2 Items'] = np.where(df['Item_Name'].isin(top2), 'top 2', None)

#  Item_Name Order_ID Top 2 Items
#0    Basket        a       top 2
#1    Carpet        b       top 2
#2    Basket        c       top 2
#3    Carpet        d       top 2
#4       Rug        e       top 2
#5       Rug        f       top 2
#6       foo        g        None
```

Comment: what is the purpose of index[0:2] here?

Comment: @SimranParajulee `.value_counts` returns a Series where the Index values are the unique values of the original Series and the values of that Series are the number of times it appeared. It returns an= descending sorted Series, so `.index[0:2]` returns the two most common values in the `'Item_Name'` column.

Comment: one more question, if there was a column called price and I wanted to get the top 10 based on total price for each item, how would I do that?